# What Azure storage option to use for images + metadata?

Tags: python, azure

I am developing a python web application hosted on Azure that requires access to a set of images and associated metadata. I have read that the best option for storing images in Azure is using Blob Storage, but I am a little confused about how to then access the images from my app. Ideally, I'd like something that would allow my app quick access to a specific image as well as its metadata. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Blob Storage it's a good thing to store your image with metadata.

Microsoft provides an example how set and retrive image with metadata using Azure SDK (in c#): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-container-properties-metadata

The best storage for this, is Azure Data Lake gen 2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-introduction
New storage generation wich use Blob Storage (low price)

In python you can configure environment follow the step in next link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python#code-examples